# Setting up simple pagination for a meteor app using Iron router and Pagination.collection()?

Tags: meteor, pagination, iron-router

Hi I have a simple app listing Posts and I am struggling to add a simple Pagination using the Iron Router along with Meteor Pagination: https://github.com/egtann/meteor-pagination

I have the following in my **index.js**:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.index.helpers({

        posts: function () {
            return Posts.find({}, {sort: {voteResult: -1}});
        },
}
```

And therefore to show the posts I am using `{{#each posts}}` in my **index.html** like this:

```
      <template name="index">
            <ul>
            {{#each posts}}
                <li>
                   {{text}}
                </li>
            {{/each}}       
            </ul>
<!-- pagination BOOTSTRAP CSS -->
    <!--    <div class="text-center">
            <ul class="pagination_bis">
              <li>
                <a href="#" aria-label="Previous">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="active_bis"><a href="#">1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
              <li>
                <a href="#" aria-label="Next">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
        </div> -->
        </template>
```

here is my **route.js**:

```
Router.configure({
    loadingTemplate: 'loading',
    notFoundTemplate: 'notFound',
    layoutTemplate: 'layout'
});

Router.route('/', function() {
    this.render('index');
});
```

***My problem:***

- How can define my routes in routes.js (Iron Router) for simple pagination ?
- How can I use the route in my index.js with a helper using the Meteor Pagination (link provided above) so that it returns only limited amount of Posts based on a perPage basis ?
- How do I connect this logic to the view (index.html) ?

I have tried to follow the example of the link I provided above but I am so confused and the the version of Meteor they used is deprecated. Needless to say that I am new to Meteor and every input is truly appreciated. For your information the app events work fine and I manage to save and remove posts, there are more than 30 posts created for testing pagination. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is an amazing resource for understanding dynamic routes and how to use data with your routes in Meteor for complete beginners: http://meteortips.com/tutorial/iron-router-part-2/

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use packages that are no longer maintained (and last commit for `egtann:meteor-pagination` was 2 years ago).

Instead simply try out [`alethes:pages`](https://atmospherejs.com/alethes/pages) ([GitHub project](https://github.com/alethes/meteor-pages)). Seems to be fairly well documented as well.

As for the router. You probably have to use URL parameters (if you want to directly access a specific page via the URL - e.g. `/posts/5/` for page 5):

```
Router.route('/posts/:page', function () {
  var pageId = this.params.page;
  ...
});
```

Comment: Can you please tell me/show me how in the html do you set `:page` equal to the postId so that it render the proper route like /posts/:page ?

Comment: Hm unfortunately not my primary domain. I think you might need a Controller (search for it in context of Iron Router). There's an example of someone doing something like that: https://crater.io/top/40 - you could inspect the source code and search for `/top/:` to find the route declaration and how they solve it.